# Jenkins service start error on red hat linux

Tags: jenkins

The jenkins service does not start when ever i run **jenkins service start**  . It says

```
 Starting Jenkins bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
                                                       [FAILED]
```

I have java installed at **/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51**. The JAVA_HOME variable is also set. Also tried adding this java to **/etc/init.d/jenkins** file. I need to use the sun jdk, not open jdk. 
Tried some of the alternatives from stackoverflow as well but did not work out. 
Any suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks,
Bhargav

Comment: How are you starting jenkins?  I'm guessing there's a script.  Have you reviewed the script for a hardcoded reference to /usr/bin/java?  If you find something like that, just remove the path from the script and let the shell resolve it.

Comment: On the terminal i wrote


            service jenkins start 

As i said, i edited the script /etc/init.d/jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Paul. The script inside **/etc/sysconfig/jenkins** needs to be edited. Else it uses the default java.

```
   JENKINS_JAVA_CMD="path of java installation"
```

Along with the above script, one can make changes to **/etc/init.d/jenkins** file if needed to add the path of java installation in your system.

Comment: Ok I'll add an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that there's a script that has /usr/bin/java hardcoded.  When you find the culprit, remove the /usr/bin so that it uses the default.  Or you can change it to use the JAVA_HOME path, something like this:

```
JAVA_EXECUTABLE=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
$JAVA_EXECUTABLE $JAVA_OPTS etc.. etc..
```